# creating combobox with parent and child items in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have 3 parent items with NR,WR,SR now NR has  N1,N2,N3 and WR has W1,W2,W3 and SR has S1,S2 child items respectively. At the initial when form loads i should have 3options to select.If i select NR then by default NR child items N1,N2,N3 should be checked.and If i select NR and after WR then i would be left with the selected items N1,N2,N3,W1,W2,W3. I want to get the selected items value and send this to the database to fetch the data.
view when NR Selected from dropdown

```
NR
(checked)N1
(checked)N2
(checked)N3
WR
ER
```

Comment: http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/. See With Optgroups Demo.

Comment: Thnanks for sharing this link. It helped me a lot ...!